# Do I have to find all magicks, moose, and secret areas in one playthrough?

Tags: achievements, steam, magicka

I've just started playing Magicka. For the achievements **I put on my robe and wizard hat**, **King's Quest**, and **Sherlock Holmes**, do I have to get everything in one playthrough?

For example, King's Quest requires you to find 12 moose. If I only have found 8 by the time I finish the game, when I replay, will I only have 4 to go or will I have to "re-tag" those 8 I already found again? Or does finding parts of these achievements "stick"?

Comment: I believe the word you are looking for is "meese". After all, if the plural of *goose* is *geese*, it serves to follow that the plural of *moose* is *meese*.

Comment: @Raven Dreamer: Actually, It is just 'moose'. ( http://www.funtrivia.com/askft/Question54218.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you revisit a moose you've already found (e.g. the first moose outside the castle) the King's Quest achievement popups up (in Steam) with your current count. So if you're found 8, but revisit an existing one, it will say 8/12.

You can do multiple runs to get these achievements, but some of the others (e.g. `Mission improbable`) require it to be completed in 1 runthrough.

Other scaling achievements would be `Bad Taste`, and `Killing your friends, you're doing it wrong`

Comment: Thanks for the additional info on the other 2 achievements!

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes No worries, I just found the list of achievements and made an educated guess. Usually if it's a summation challenge, e.g. 9000 kills, without the disclaimer of 'in one game' then it's cumulative over many games. Achievements of '9000 damage at once', then you know it's on a per attack basis, etc.